# How to loop through data with empty rows with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through non-contiguous data - basically loop through all the cells that have value in `Range("K:M")` taking into consideration that between the data there might be some empty rows and I will need to skip and move on and merge the *3* cells into *1* in `Range("H4")`.

Tried different approaches but every time it hits the empty row it stops. Below will be more like an infinite loop that does what I need but can't work how to break out at some point when there is no more data.

```
Sub GenerateStyleFabricColourV2()
        Dim srcData As Range
        Dim RowNum As Long
        RowNum = 4
        Set srcData = Range("K:M")
        If Not IsEmpty(srcData.Value) Then
          Do While IsEmpty(RowNum) = False
            Cells(RowNum, 8).Value = Cells(RowNum, 11).Value & Cells(RowNum, 12).Value &  Cells(RowNum, 13).Value
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
          Loop
        End If
        Range("H4").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     End Sub
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` refers to a cell that may or may not have a value (i.e. blank or not blank). It isn't intended to do anything with an integer. Maybe `Do While Not  IsEmpty(Cells(RowNum, 8))`

Comment: If only column K and M have values, do you still want to concatenate K, L and M into column H?

Comment: @Jeeped yes as long as there is a value in K,L,M will like to concatenate. My only problem is when there is a blank row that's when the problems appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IsEmpty` refers to a cell that may or may not have a value (i.e. blank or not blank). It isn't intended to do anything with an integer.

```
Sub GenerateStyleFabricColourV2()
    Dim srcData As Range
    Dim rowNum As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        lastRow = Application.Max(4, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
        With .Cells(4, "H").Resize(lastRow - 4 + 1, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[3]&rc[4]&rc[5]"
            .Value = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great answer because of the little amount of time it will take due to the use of formulas instead of loops.

Comment: Plus 1 for the absence of loops and smart way of getting last row over 3 columns

Comment: Oooo i didnt even notice that. I am tempted to see how much of a time saver it is though. BRB testing

Comment: this is signifcantly faster. I control+d to the end of the sheet -1 (b/c xlup doesnt work if you fill out the entire sheet) & it took 10.25 seconds to do the entire sheet where as mine took 106 seconds.

Comment: @Jeeped Your approach is blazing fast I can't believe how fast it is to be honest just blows you away. For some reason `With Worksheets("sheet2")` gives me subscript out of range 9 to get it to work i just entered `With Worksheets(2)` but other than that just amazing I'm speechless how fast it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GenerateStyleFabricColourV2()
    Dim srcData As Range, rcell As Range

    Set srcData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:K" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each rcell In srcData.Cells
        rcell.Offset(0, -3).Value = rcell.Value & rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value & rcell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Next rcell

 End Sub
```

This is pretty straight forward. I like looping through the one column and using offset. I might be over simplifying it though.

Comment: your method is fast too again for some reason i get the same run time error 9 don't know why same fix instead of the `Sheet1` just use `2` to reference my sheet other than that works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

This simple code is very easy & effective too,,

For a = 1 to lastrow

if cells(a,1) = "" then

goto lastline

Here you can put your codes

lastline:

Next a